# Visual Composer creating own shortcodes with vc_map() to return simple Image

Tags: functions, images, shortcode

I am using the Plugin Visual Composer with in a new Theme I develop. My question is about mapping shortcodes to Visual Composer arrays.

The problem I get, when I try to make a custom element for an image. So here is what I did:

I created an php file `vc_shortcodes.php` for my arrays of params. The matching shortcodes are in `functions.php`.

For the array type `textarea_html` everything works fine and I can see me text as supposed at the front end.

Now I am trying to us an array with type `attach_image`. It is the following:

```
/Bild
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'webnuts_bild' );
function webnuts_bild() {
    vc_map( array(
        "name" => __( "Bild", "my-text-domain" ),
        "base" => "image_url",
        "icon" => "icon-webnuts",
        'admin_enqueue_css' => array('/wp-content/themes/devdmbootstrap3-child/framework/css/admin-wn.css' ),
        "class" => "wn-bild",
        "category" => __( "Content", "my-text-domain"),
        "params" => array(
            array(
                "type" => "attach_image",
                "holder" => "img",
                "class" => "",
                "heading" => __( "Hintergrundbild", "my-text-domain" ),
                "param_name" => "image_url",
                "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" ),
                "description" => __( "Bitte wähle hier ein Bild aus oder lade eins hoch", "my-text-domain" )
            )
        )
    ) );
}
```

It works so far, that I can chose the element in the backend an attach an image to it. But I guess I make something wrong in the functions.php

I am sure I make something wrong in `functions.php`... There I use the following:

```
add_shortcode( 'image_url', 'bild_func' );
function bild_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'image_url' => 'Bild wird nicht richtig angezeigt'
    ), $atts ) );

    return "<div class='bild-wrapper'><img src='" . "{$image_url}" . "'/></div>";
}
```

This is what gets returned in the browser:

```
<div class="bild-wrapper">
    <img src="9">
</div>
```

What do I have to change so the image gets shown in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Composer adds the image ID to the generated shortcode. This gives you more flexibility with image sizes. You can use it like this:

```
$imageSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_url, 'thumbnail');
if( $imageSrc ) {
    echo '<img src="' . $imageSrc[0] . '" />';
}
```

The `thumbnail` param could be replaced by `medium` or another valid image size. The `if` clause is there to verify that the image is really there (not deleted).

Advice: Rename the `param_name` to `image_id` so you won't get confused when using the code later.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

Comment: Please add an explanation **why** this solves the issue - thanks.

Comment: Ok that seems to be simple! I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use you image url by your attachment id that already shown. So just use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` to get the attachment url. like:

```
add_shortcode( 'image_url', 'bild_func' );
function bild_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'image_url' => ''
    ), $atts ) );

    /* Let's get the URL from that image */
    if(isset($a['image_url'])) {
       $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $a['image_url'], 'full' );;
     } else {
       $image_url = ''; // default image or something if you want.
     }

    return "<div class='bild-wrapper'><img src='" . "{$image_url[0]}" . "'/></div>";
}
```

Hope it make sense !

Answer (score 0):

Visual Composer does the right thing with providing the image id because you can the get the image in the best size for your needs. You could do it like that:

```
// Replace 'thumbnail' with any valid wordpress image size.
$imageSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_url, 'thumbnail'); 
// Check if the image is still there
if( $imageSrc ) {
    echo '<img src="' . $imageSrc[0] . '" />';
}
```

You could also rename the 'param_name' in 'vc_map' to 'image_id' so you understand the code later.